# save two data frames in the same .csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on these data frames, but I wonder if I can save them all in a .csv file?

```
li=[65, 98, 55, 62, 79, 59, 51, 90, 72, 56, 70, 62, 66, 80, 94, 79, 63, 73, 71, 85]
datos= pd.DataFrame(li)
t=datos.values.tolist()

lo=np.sort(t,axis=None)

f=pd.Series(lo).value_counts()

f1=pd.DataFrame({'frecuencias':f})

f2=f/len(lo)
f3=pd.DataFrame({'frecuencias relativa':f2})
```

Here I have two data frames that I would like to save in the same file. I have tried the following:

`f1,f3.to_csv('vacio.csv')`
but it gives me a mess or not what I expected the two tables to show one below the other, I hope your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

You should `concat` both the dataframe as follows:

```
final_df = pd.concat([f1,f3],axis=1)
```

then `final_df` save this to csv as `final_df.to_csv("test.csv",drop=True)`

You can see in the csv as following output:

```
    frecuencias     frecuencias relativa
62  2   0.10
79  2   0.10
63  1   0.05
66  1   0.05
70  1   0.05
71  1   0.05
72  1   0.05
73  1   0.05
80  1   0.05
51  1   0.05
85  1   0.05
```